# Add users to Woocommerce without email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce for a store.
A plugin makes a request at this url

```
https://domain.ca/wc-api/v3/customers?...
```

And then receive an error:

```
ConstraintError: Unable to add key to index 'email': at least one key does not satisfy the uniqueness requirements.
```

I would like to know how I could bypass this error message. In other words, how could I modify Wordpress so that the email field is not required by Woocommerce?

Comment: The field email is required by woocommerce, to send emails when command are done, prepared, ..., the wc-api is used for ajax POST, for exemple. From which page your informations are coming from ?

Comment: I think WordPress requires it even for regular users.

Comment: Ok then I think I should find a way to bypass this. Thank you

Comment: You cannot have more than one user with the same email address by default in WordPress. You should try this plug-in which claims to override that functionality: https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-multiple-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one user with the same email address by default in WordPress. You should try this plug-in which claims to override that functionality:

[Allow Multiple Accounts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-multiple-accounts/)